# Basic Reference material about ODEs such as saparability with calculations and examples?

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show this kind of non-linear $y''''=y'y''/(1+x)$ in normal form. For example here if $y=e^{x}\rightarrow y^{(n)}=e^{x}\rightarrow x=-1$, where $y^{(n)}$ means $n$th differential, then $x=-1$, too weak idea. When I google with `differential` or anything like that, most of the material does not look the material that I need. I need to solve different type of problems such as this homework

$$\begin{cases} u'=(u+v)^{2} \\ v''=x+u'v'  \end{cases} $$

I am not requesting you to solve them but I am requesting some material because I find my book quite hard-reading in this section. The earlier chapter begun that something is something, without much further ado really `why?`, and now the next `advanced` chapters are referring to the past chapters. The idea is a rush introduction to this topic in an engineering course so I think it explains quite a bit about the pedagogy.

Comment: Which book are you using now? Also, the usual notation is $y^{(n)}$ for the $n^\text{th}$ `derivative`. For the first problem, you might need a series solution.

Comment: @bgins: reading the same old foreign book as in my earlier questions about Indefinite integral, now in the section about differentials, sorry I wish I had the book as online or English version... I does cover some theory but not introduce the methods to really solve this kind of things, very well it is thick (1k pages and quite inaccessible)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out David Joyner's excellent [2007 (draft) book](http://wdjoyner.com/teach/DiffyQ/des-book.pdf).

One method that would work for the first equation, $y^{(4)}=\frac{y'y''}{1+x}$, would be the power series or [series solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations) or [Frobenius method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html). The method consists of assuming a [Taylor/Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) form:
$$
y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
$$
which (after adjusting the summation variable
$n$ to ignore the leading terms which are zero)
has $k^\text{th}$ derivative
$$
y^{(k)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+k)!}{n!}a_{n+k}x^n
$$
so that, equating terms with the same power of $x$,
the differential equation becomes a recurrence relation
on the sequence $\{a_n\}$ of coefficients,
with the first few ($4$ in our case)
free (to match initial condidions)
and the rest determined:
$$
\sum\frac{(n+4)!}{n!}a_{n+4}x^n=
\left(\sum\frac{(n+2)!}{n!}a_{n+2}x^n\right)
\left(\sum(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n\right)
\left(\sum(-1)^nx^n\right)
$$
$$
\forall{n}:\quad
a_{n+4}=\frac{n!}{(n+4)!}
\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}
\sum_{k=0}^j
(k+2)(k+1)
(j-k+1)
a_{k+2}
a_{j-k+1}
$$
where the summations above with no indices specified are for $n\ge 0$
and the coefficients of the product of two series were found with
a kind of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) formula,
$$
\left(\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n\right)
\left(\sum_{n\ge0}b_nx^n\right)=
\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}\right)x^n.
$$
So for instance
$$a_4=\frac{2a_1a_2}{4!}$$
$$a_5=\frac{2a_2(3a_3+2a_2-a_1)}{5!}$$
and so on. You need to be able to estimate the growth of the $a_n$ and use a ratio or root test to determine the radius of convergence of your series, and in some cases, you will be able to find an analytic solution.

Comment: ...is this term $\left(\sum(-1)^nx^n\right)$ for the divisor $1+x$?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: When I read your answer, I think my book (p.427) has a mistake: it apparently claims that `"the exponent function of the form"`  $E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ax)^{k}}{k!}$ `"is an unique solution to any initial-valued DY problem"` and then it in a rush of sentence states that $e^{x}$ some sort of basic solution. Sorry the book actually states nothing, it more like outlines things and then requires one to calcutale things...feeling that a lot of gaps here.

Comment: How do you deal with divisors if you have them such as $1+x+y'''$ or $1+x+x^{2}+y'''+y^{(5)}$? Like the first one, I cannot immeadiately see a geometric serie -- perhaps to separate it if with the above case and then just one-by-one use the convolution rule for every part?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $r=x+1$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^4y}{dr^4}=\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{dy}{dr}\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}$

$r\dfrac{d^4y}{dr^4}=\dfrac{dy}{dr}\dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}$

Let $u=\dfrac{dy}{dr}$ ,

Then $r\dfrac{d^3u}{dr^3}=u\dfrac{du}{dr}$

$\int r\dfrac{d^3u}{dr^3}~dr=\int u\dfrac{du}{dr}~dr$

$\int r~d\left(\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}\right)=\int u~du$

$r\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-\int \dfrac{d^2y}{dr^2}~dr=\int u~du$

$r\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-\dfrac{du}{dr}=\dfrac{u^2}{2}+C_1$