# $y''=(y')^{3} e^{y}$, some easy way to solve this non-linear differential equation?

Tags: integration

The last time when I thought that the task was about solving a non-linear differential equation with convolution and Frobenius -method more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109189/basic-reference-material-about-odes-such-as-saparability-with-calculations-and-e/109217#109217), my instructor cheered me up that the goal was some sort of numerical approximation for the non-linear differential equation with first-order differentials -- it used the term to solve in `"system form"` which was at best misleading (well I never understood how it really was meant like that but here is a next puzzle). The task is to solve this `"with integrals"` or actually it uses some slang `"kvadratures"` in the assignment. I am now unsure whether I should use many times chain-rule and solve it with brute-force or whether there is some elegant way to solve this with `"with kvadratures"`? I am not sure whether the author is now referring to some numerical method or does it mean really just to integrate it and solve it?

Page 633 in the foreign book I have been doing -- sorry no English version available and the book has not been peer-reviewed.

Comment: Did you tried using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%3D%28y%27%29%5E3+e%5Ey)? It can also shows you a step-by-step solution.

Comment: "kvadratures" in English is "quadratures", meaning integrals: a solution involving integrals (which may or may not be possible to do in closed form).

Comment: In this case "quadratures" is a bit of a red herring.  Hint: change of variables $y(t) = x, t = T(x)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: $y''=(y(t))''=(x)''=(1)'=0$ and $(y(t)')^{3}=(x')^{3}=1^{3}=1$ so $0=e^{y}$ and this is absurd?! $y(t)=x$? But why? And now some $t=T(x)$ but for which reason?

Comment: Let $v = \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{T'(x)}$.  Then $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{T'(x)} \frac{dv}{dx} = -\frac{T''(x)}{T'(x)^3}$, and the differential equation becomes $-\frac{T''(x)}{T'(x)^3} = \frac{1}{T'(x)^3} e^x$ or $T''(x) = - e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$y'' = (y')^3 e^{y}$$

$$\dfrac{y''}{y'^2} = y' e^{y}$$

$$-d\left\{\dfrac{1}{y'}\right\} = d\{ e^{y}\}$$

$$-\dfrac{1}{y'}= e^y+C$$

$$-1= y' e^y+Cy'$$

$$C_1-x= e^y+Cy$$

See this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111185/using-the-lambert-w-to-express-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation) on how to use the [Lambert W](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) -function to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello Pedro, I am not sure but is the Lambert W function related to this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553594/what-is-a-simple-form-of-this-integral)? If I understand correctly, the generating function of Abel's polynomial has a Lambert W function and the integral has Abel's polynomial. Able to look at the integral?

Comment: I would stick to Stephen Montgomery-Smith's comment.

Answer (score 0):

substitute : $y'_x= v \Rightarrow y''_x=v'_y\cdot v~$ so :

$$v'_y \cdot v = v^3 \cdot e^y \Rightarrow v'_y =v^2 \cdot e^y \Rightarrow \frac {dv}{dy}=v^2 \cdot e^y \Rightarrow \int \frac{dv}{v^2}=\int e^y \,dy$$