# Using the Lambert W to express a solution of a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I solved a differential equation some time ago and I need to solve for $y$. How can we solve for $y$ using the Lambert W function?

$$C_1+x = e^y+Cy$$

Comment: ...related problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/110139/5902), interesting how things evolve :)

Comment: @hhh Infinite loop!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\large C^{-1}\exp\left(C^{-1}e^y+y\right)=(C^{-1} e^y)e^{(C^{-1} e^y)} $$

**Answer**

> $$\hskip 2in \displaystyle \begin{array}{} A+x=e^y+Cy \\ \frac{A+x}{C}=\frac{e^y}{C}+y \\ \frac{1}{C}\exp\left(\frac{A+x}{C}\right)=\frac{e^y}{C}\exp\left(\frac{e^y}{C}\right) \\ W\left(\frac{1}{C}e^{(A+x)/C}\right)=\frac{e^y}{C}  \\ y=\log\left[ C\; W\left(\frac{1}{C}e^{(A+x)/C}\right)\right] \end{array}$$

Note also that $\log W(z)=\log z-W(z)$, if you want to compare with what [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+A%2Bx+%3D+e%5Ey+%2B+C+y+for+y) gives.

Comment: So you have $$y = \log W\left( {\frac{{{C_1} + x}}{{{C^2}}}} \right) + \log C$$ ?

Comment: @Peter: No, you forgot to exponentiate the LHS of the original equation.

Comment: I was too focused on the RHS. How do you code that spoiler? It's really cool to make answers.

Comment: @Peter: It's problematic putting `$$\LaTeX$$` in spoilers so you'll have to check what markup I used there, but the spoiler code is `>! text`. You may be able to see an "Edit" button and see what I wrote down.

Comment: Thanks. I mostly use MathType's "translator" to code my equations, but I know a little of LaTeX so I think I can manage.