# What is a simple form of this integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, singular-integrals

This integral reminds me of something familiar but I cannot remember the rule to make it simple.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\exp(i a \cdot v)}v \mathrm d v$$

where $a$ is a scalar for simplicity now.

**What is the method to expand this integral?**

Comment: Fourier transform of a function.

Comment: Or you can use the residue theory of complex analysis

Comment: Is A a matrix?  Is v a vector or a scalar.  Please clarify.

Comment: @BettyMock It was initially intended to be matrix, but I simplified the problem to solve first the equation with scalar one.

Comment: Google "Hilbert transform."  The $1/v$ term is singular, so special care needs to be taken doing the integral (see "principle value").

Comment: The integral only exists as a principal value.

Comment: Using the Cauchy integral formula, you could express it as a line integral around a half circle with radius R and the interval (-R,R).  The integral formula says that has to be $2 \pi i$ f(0).   Since f(v) = $e^{iav}$ it is 1 at v = 0.  You then need to figure out this integral over the circle part of the curve, which will depend on R.  That plus the integral along the x-axis must = $2 \pi i$.  Once you have the integral over the curve, you expand $R \rightarrow \infty$ . You can finish it up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Residue Theorem and Cauchy Integral Formula

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\exp(i a \cdot v)}v \mathrm d v = -i \pi.$$

The function has a singularity on the contour at $z = 0$.
Make a small detour around $z = 0$ to avoid the problem.
Pick a small $\rho > 0$ and consider a contour consisting of the arc $A_{R}$ followed by a line segment along a real axis between $-R$ and $-\rho$, followed by an upper semi-circle centered at $0$ with radius $\rho$ and, finally, a line segment along the positive part of the real exit from $\rho$ to $R$.
Call the contour $B_{R,\rho}$ and denote the line segments by $L_{-}$ and $L_{+}$, respectively and the small semi-circle by $A_{\rho}$.
The function is analytic with $B_{R,\rho}$.
Its integral along this contour is 0:
\begin{equation}
\int_{A_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz = 0
+ \int_{-R}^{-\rho} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx
+ \int_{A_{\rho}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz
+ \int_{\rho}^{R} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx.
\end{equation}
Because
\begin{equation}
\int_{-R}^{-\rho} \frac{e^{ix}}{x} dx 
= - \int_{\rho}^{R} \frac{e^{-ix}}{x} dx,
\end{equation}
by combining the second the fourth integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\rho}^{R} \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{x} dx
+ \int_{A_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz
+ \int_{A_{\rho}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz = 0.
\end{equation}
Because the integrand in the leftmost integral is
\begin{equation}
2i \cdot \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2ix} = 2i \cdot \frac{sin(x)}{x}
\end{equation}
so we get
\begin{equation}
2i \int_{\rho}^{R} \frac{sin(x)}{x} dx 
= - \int_{A_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz - \int_{A_{\rho}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz = 0
\end{equation}
and dividing by $2i$
\begin{equation}
\int_{\rho}^{R} \frac{sin(x)}{x} dx 
= \frac{i}{2} 
\Big( \int_{A_{R}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz
+ \int_{A_{\rho}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz
\Big).
\end{equation}
So the integral over $A_{R}$ vanishes as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and got the result.

*Source: Hitczenko P. Some applications of the residue theorem MATH322, 2005.*

Answer (score 1):

*I am working on this. Perhaps [Fourier Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554786/how-is-fourier-transform-related-to-hilbert-transform) best tool here as suggested by Stephen? Anyway below some novel ideas!*

**Related to Abel's polynomial?**

> Consider [Abel's
>   polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelPolynomial.html) where
>
> $$f(t)=t e^{at}$$
>
> and now divide by $t^{-2}$ so
>
> $$\frac{f(t)}{t^2}=\frac 1 t e^{at}$$
>
> and now your equation is
>
> $$\frac 1 v e^{iav}:=\frac 1 v e^{z v}$$
>
> that is perhaps related to the questions
>
> > 1. [Using the Lambert W to express a solution of a differential equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111185/using-the-lambert-w-to-express-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation)
> > 2. its DY [$y''=(y')^{3} e^{y}$, some easy way to solve this non-linear differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110116/y-y3-ey-some-easy-way-to-solve-this-non-linear-differential-equati/110139#110139).
>
> where I encountered the Lambert W that is in the generating function
>   of $\frac 1 v e^{z v}$.

**Possible to reformulate the function somehow to make it easier to solve?**

> > *"This integral reminds me of something familiar -- $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\exp(i a \cdot v)}v \mathrm d v$"*.
>
> You are probably thinking of [Laurent's
>   series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentSeries.html) and [Cauchy's
>   Integral
>   theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_theorem)
>
> [image]
>
> where the path $\gamma$ needs to be connected. Now let $\frac{\exp(i a
> > v)}v=\frac{\exp(i a v)}{\exp(\log(v))}=\exp(iav-log(v))$. I cannot yet
>   see how to reformulate this question to use such theorems because the
>   function should be analytic, investigating 
>   [What is $iav-\log(v)$? Any series expansion or inequality for it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554674/what-is-iav-logv-any-series-expansion-or-inequality-for-it).