# What is $iav-\log(v)$? Any series expansion or inequality for it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality

I am investigating the integral of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553594/what-is-a-simple-form-of-this-integral) where

\begin{equation}
\frac{\exp(i a v)}v=\frac{\exp(i a v)}{\exp(\log(v))}=\exp(iav-log(v)) 
\end{equation}

where I am interested in the parameter

\begin{equation}
iav-\log(v).
\end{equation}

What is this?
Is there any series form for this or some inequality to get an easier form?

I recall that there were some series close to this or some inequality such as [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) to get some approximation? Perhaps  some other form of this such as $iv-\log(v)$ or $v-log(v)$ could be easier puzzle first to think about?

Comment: You could try the Taylor expansion for $\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ but I don't think that would get you anywhere.  Generally speaking, when there's an expression of the form $P(x)e^{Q(x)}$, where $P,Q$ are polynomials, there's no nice way to simplify that I know of.

Comment: Probably, some Galois theory can be used here.